# Sqlalchemy: how to filter multiple conditions with filter_rule

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using python and sqlalchemy and want to perform a query with filters, using `filter_rule`.

I have these DB records:

```
{"name":"xyz","age":40,"location":"ABC","salary":10000}
```

And I would like to make a query like this:

```
select * from my_table where age<50 and salary>8000;
```

I understand that I can use `filter_rule="model.age < 50 and model.salary > 8000"` but it doesn't seem to work properly for me with the greater than and less than symbols.

However, the `filter_rule` works perfectly fine if I have equality conditions like `age==50` and `salary==10000`.

Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 3):

```
from sqlalchemy import and_
filter_rule = and_(model.age<50, model.salary>8000)
```

Comment: Can you provide a full example of selecting data with this filter rule?